# How to construct an object in javascript not an array object using push method or similar

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to build a javascript object through the push method of an array. There are some loops inside to fill the values, but the result is a matrix. I know it's an object too, but I like to use dot notation to use the resulting object.
How to do this and achieve an object, not an array

```
    let person = [{
    age: 0,
    name: "",
    second_name: "",
    objeto2: {
        name2: "",
        second_name2: ""
    }
}]
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    person.push({ age: i, name: i + 1, second_name: "segundo", objeto2: { name2: "xxsxs", second_name2: "adfa" } })
};
```

the results:

```
[ { age: 0,
    name: '',
    second_name: '',
    objeto2: { name2: '', second_name2: '' } },
  { age: 1,
    name: 2,
    second_name: 'segundo',
    objeto2: { name2: 'xxsxs', second_name2: 'adfa' } },
  { age: 2,
    name: 3,
    second_name: 'segundo',
    objeto2: { name2: 'xxsxs', second_name2: 'adfa' } },
  { age: 3,
    name: 4,
    second_name: 'segundo',
    objeto2: { name2: 'xxsxs', second_name2: 'adfa' } } ]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Why do you want it to be an object? This seems better suited to be an array.

Comment: I prefer to use dot notation rather [] and them... the dot notation

Comment: use a value within an object as a key. This creates associative objects.

{
   foo: {
    name: "foo",
   }
}

Comment: @kamome That's a horrible idea. If you have indexed properties, you should use an array. There's no excuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
let person = {
  "$0": {age:0, name:"", alias:"", "$1":{name:"", alias:""}}
};
for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
  let j = Object.keys(person).length;
  person["$"+j] = {age:j, name:j+1, alias:"segundo", "$1":{name:"xxsxs", alias:"adfa"}};
}

console.log(person);
console.log(person.$2.$1.name);
console.log(person.$3.alias);
console.log(person.$3.$1.alias);
```

**codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoGoKp?editors=0012**

- In objects, properties always need a key (`$1`,`$2`,etc).
  And those keys always have to be a string, numbers will be automatically typecasted into strings: [see this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) (under "Property names").
- For the above reason, and specific to dot-notation itself, [you cannot use only a number](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781) to access the object's properties when using dot-notation. Using `person.2.1.name` is not possible. Therefor I prepended the numbers with `$`, so it becomes `person.$2.$1.name`, which is possible.
  *You can change `$` to any other valid character, like `_`, but I found this the most readable.*
- In order to be able to 'push' the next property to the end of the existing object, I use [`Object.keys(person).length`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object) to get the next available index number.
  Note that in your case you could also use the integer `i` from the for-loop, but `Object.keys().length` most closely resembles the `Array.push()` method.
  Also, if at a later point you would need to add another couple of properties, you wouldn't have to alter your for-loop to correct for the index numbers. Now, the `3` in `i<3;` stands for the number of properties you want to add to the object, so if later on you wanted to add another 5 properties, your for-loop would start like `for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {` and everything else would stay the same. You could even make a function for it to make it more flexible:

  ```
  function addPersons(n) {
    for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
      let j = Object.keys(person).length;
      person["$"+j] = {age:j, name:j+1, alias:"segundo", "$1":{name:"xxsxs", alias:"adfa"}};
    }
  }
  addPersons(3);
  addPersons(5);
  ```